# How to access and manage others YouTube channel using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am working on a project that helps YouTubers to access their youtube channels and update details video details. So far, I have created a youtube developer account, setup credentials and OAuth consent screen with youtube v3 API in scope.

I can successfully sign-in any user using the google sign-in button at the frontend (NextJS) and send the client id and credentials to the backend (NodeJS).

```
router.post("/google", function (req, res) {
    try {
        const { clientId, credential } = req.body;
        const user = jwt.decode(credential);
        console.log("clientId", clientId);
        console.log("user", user);

        return res.status(200).json({
            message: "google",
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: error.message,
            data: error.data,
            errCode: 500,
        });
    }
})
```

Now, I want to get youtube channel details and a list of videos of the signed user so I tried this,

```
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    process.env.REDIRECT_URL
);

// get youtube channel details
const youtube = google.youtube({
    version: "v3",
    auth: oauth2Client,
});
        
youtube.channels.list({
    part: "snippet",
    id: user.googleId,
},(err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("err", err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
        console.log("data", data);
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }
});
```

But this code gives the error,

> No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set

Still, I don't under how this function will give signed youtube channels details when I am not providing any parameters to youtube API. Now, I am confused more than ever.

Can you help me figure out, how I can my app access others youtube channels? What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing `auth` param. Look at `getChannel` https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: I read the documentation, first, they want users to sign-in using the Google consent screen then sign-in again with youtube scope to add your channel.

Comment: You still need to pass `credentials` from `/google` endpoint to `list({})` as an `auth` parameter

Comment: Consent screen is not sign in (authentication) it is authorization there is a difference.

Comment: Does that mean I have to ask users to sign-in twice to get their youtube permission?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an authorized oauth client to the YouTube api method.  YOurs has not bee authorized.

you should follow the official [Node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs) bellow find the two methods from the sample that you are missing.

```
/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Do I need to store the access token and refresh token in the database?

Comment: you should store the refresh token somewhere if you want the code to work without requesting authorization the next time it runs

Comment: The sample shows it being stored in TOKEN_PATH